# intercarlar un solo array con solo algoritmos (lógica de programación)

Tags: java, array, c, algoritmos

No se permite crear otro array.

```
int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

salida o return = 10,1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5
```

Comment: Hola, entiendo que esto es un ejercicio de programacion, por ende para mejorar uno mismo, no es mejor intentarlo en ves de pedir la solucion??

Comment: Claro que lo he intentado pero no logro hacer el intercalado, simplemente ordeno de mayor a menor y viceversa.

Comment: mmm bueno, No se puede nisiquiera crear un array auxiliar?

Comment: ¿Notaste que toma el último número, luego el primero, luego penúltimo, luego segundo, etc...?

Comment: La dificultad del problema era que no se puede usar collections (array,list).

Comment: @Programer, pero no has colocado qué has intentado, debes [edit] la pregunta con el código que has usado para intentar resolver este error y *(si el código arroja errores)*, agrega la descripción de los errores obtenidos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La dificultad del ejercicio  está en que no se pueda crear un array auxiliar. Se entiende por tanto que lo único que se permite es desplazar los datos dentro del array existente.

El algoritmo sería más o menos el siguiente:

- Empezar con `i=0`
- Repetir:

  - Tomar copia del último elemento del array
  - Desplazar hacia la derecha todos los elementos desde el `i` en adelante (de este modo "hacemos hueco" para meter un dato)
  - Meter en `array[i]` la copia del último elemento
  - Incrementar `i` en 2.
- mientras `i` sea menor que la longitud del array

Estos pasos son todos ellos bastante triviales, excepto el de "desplazar hacia la derecha". Este desplazamiento se hace comenzando por el final del array y copiando en cada elemento lo que había en el anterior, hasta llegar al elemento `i` en que paramos.

Mira un par de iteraciones en forma gráfica, para convencerte de que funciona:

[image: Iteraciones]

El triangulito rojo representa el valor de `i`. En cada iteración se copia a una variable auxiliar el último elemento de la lista, se desplazan a la derecha todos los datos desde ese triangulito al final, y se mete en el lugar señalado por el triangulito el que teníamos en la variable auxiliar.

Si sigues mentalmente o en papel unas cuantas iteraciones más, verás que funciona.

---

Esta es la implementación Python. Te dejo como ejercicio que lo traduzcas a Java o C:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

i = 0
while i<len(lista):
    ultimo = lista[-1]
    for j in range(len(lista)-1, i, -1):
        lista[j] = lista[j-1]
    lista[i] = ultimo
    i+= 2
print(lista)
```

---

```
[10, 1, 9, 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Intenté realizar la conversión de Python a Java, pero no logre hacer el recorrido. La explicación que pusiste es bastante clara y se entiende perfectamente que hay que hacer para lograr ordenarlo. Pero no logro plasmar esa lógica en código de Java.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el metodo que aplicas es correcto.

Comment: Entonces... ¿has conseguido implementarlo en Java o no? En caso negativo deberías editar la pregunta (o hacer otra) y poner el código que has hecho de momento, y explicar qué parte no consigues que funcione. Hasta el momento no has puesto ni un ejemplo de código propio, por lo que no hay pruebas de que lo hayas intentado. Stack Overflow es para preguntar dudas, no para pedir que te hagan una tarea completa.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes dejar un lista desordenada, cabe señalar que es una forma

```
List<Integer> listaOrdenada = new ArrayList<>();
    listaOrdenada.add(1);
    listaOrdenada.add(2);
    listaOrdenada.add(3);
    listaOrdenada.add(4);
    for (Integer integer : listaOrdenada) {
        System.out.println("Lista ordenada "+integer);
    }
    System.out.println("###################");
    Collections.shuffle(listaOrdenada);
    Set<Integer>  listaDesordenada = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
    listaDesordenada.addAll(listaOrdenada);
    for (Integer integer : listaDesordenada) {
        System.out.println("Lista ordenada "+integer);
    }
```

Comment: El código no debe pegarse como imagen, sino como código. Mira aqui como hacerlo: https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Comment: OK, gracias no tenia idea.